How to create an SFTP user with access to bash?
You are my last hope, you've been killing on this task for about a week.
I need to create two users, both SFTP.
User1 must have access to /var/www and absolutely everything in the directory, full rights. (I seem to have been more or less successful with this, but sometimes the rights fly away, how can you deal with it?)
User2 must have access to /var/www/site/dev/project, also SFTP, but with access to bash so that he can deplot the back-end part in Java
They should both work in the same directory, because user1 also has access to the same directory as user2. root can also edit these files, but so that users do not have rights.
I've dug everything from YT with Hindus to complete GPT violence, I can't find a working solution, everything is constantly breaking down.
I'm asking for your help... Thank you in advance!
Ubuntu 22 04

"User1 must have access to /var/www and absolutely everything in the directory, full rights." Bad idea. Always use a personal dir for users for ftp and let the system rsync the files to the website.  That way you can 1st make a backup and have a restore point.

I'm not the Ubuntu pro so far but did a few things with SSH and SFTP, so let me share my (untested) thoughts - hopefully it may help a step forwards.

I assume you want to use SFTP on OpenSSH-Server, correct?
I would checkout to use user specific config files for SSH-access:
double check your /etc/ssh/sshd_config if it includes the /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
Then create two text files as user specific configs and put them under /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/, let's call it "user1.conf" and "user2.conf":

user1.conf
Match User User1
   ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /www
   # Maybe you have to set the umask to the ForceCommand line by adding -u 002 or whatever may be correct for your case.
   ChrootDirectory /var

user2.conf
Match User User2
   # Here I'm not sure about the umask-integration if necessary.
   ChrootDirectory /var/www/site/dev/project

The line "ForceCommand internal-sftp" should limit the user's SSH usage to SFTP, so that he should not be able to login with a shell session like bash.
Me by myself like to set the users shell to "/usr/sbin/nologin" in the "etc/passwd" additionally.

After this you will have to restart the sshd daemon. (Little hint from my side: restart it, but stay connected in the running session while checking in another session that you still can login. So if anything should have gone wrong you may have the chance to correct it or to remove the changes without locking yourself out.)
Regarding the permissions: As far as I know files and folders in Ubuntu are created with the creating user as owner and it's primary group as owner group. So you could check if it could be a solution to create a new group "xyz" and add both users to it. Then you would have to set the new owner manually after creating new files and folders - alternatively you could use this new group as the primary group for both user accounts (give it a thought about the security aspects).
Regarding the flying away permissions I don't have an explanation so far. Maybe their behaviour depend on some other conditions like the way of access or another client or something like that.


Hi @Rinzwind,
thanks for your feedback. Understood and taken with me.
Instead of your recommendation the rest of my thoughts - excepting the direct dir access - should still fit, doesn't it?
